# Why aren't fields in Record optional?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Currently, `Record<K, T>` is defined as:

```
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
};
```

Why isn't it defined as:

```
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]?: T;
};
```

That seems like it would be safer, because in most cases you would need to verify that a particular key existed on the object before you could go ahead and read it.

Comment: Where is this coming from?  Usually I use `Record<K, T>` when I'm sure that the value in question has a property of type `T` for every key in `K`.  If I'm not sure, then yes, I'd use `Partial<Record<K, T>>`. But often you *are* sure that a value has a set of keys (e.g., after you verify, or you construct it that way).

Comment: I think you are just thinking about then you access the members, but you can use record to ensure the fields are specified, your version would make all fields optional

Comment: In most cases where I've seen a Record used, it's in a place where the keys change so you can't know them ahead of time. If you know the keys ahead of time an interface makes more sense.

Comment: @jcalz That's what type guards are for. You can verify that a member exists, then you can use the member and the compiler will know that it is in the record.

Comment: I also often find myself second guessing decisions made by the TypeScript maintainers, but usually it just comes down to difference of opinion.  My use cases aren't always what they consider most important, and vice versa.  They had their reasons for defining `Record<K,T>` the way it is; it's used a lot in libraries; developers use it in their code.  If you want to define your own version like `BetterRecord<K, T>` and use it, you're free to do so.  I doubt that there's any official answer to this question, so I'm voting to close as primarily opinion-based.   Good luck!

Comment: I agree that TypeScript is cornering you one way or the other.

`const addressBook : Record<string, string> = { "John": "Rainbow Road 1", "Peter": "Heaven Road 1" };
const marrysAddress = addressBook["Marry"])`

Here it will think that the type of `marrysAddress` is a `string` which is a nonsense.

`const addressBook : Record<string, string | undefined> = { "John": "Rainbow Road 1", "Peter": "Heaven Road 1" };
const addresses = Object.values(addressBook)`

Here it will think that the type of `addresses` is `(string | undefined)[]` which is another nonsense.